# Drag multiple elements that aren't grouped in a `g` tag?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using D3's [drag behavior](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior) to drag circle elements in a force layout with `circleGroup.call(force.drag)`, where `force.drag` is a drag behavior and `circleGroup` is a selection of all circle elements. This works fine for dragging a single element.

How can I drag an arbitrary selection of multiple circle elements all at once?

Note that because the selection must be arbitrary, I don't think I can just just group the ones I want to drag together in a `<g>` tag.

I've looked at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491660/parenting-d3-js-nodes-for-dragging) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921777/how-to-move-drag-and-drop-multiple-shapes-with-d3) and still haven't been able to get it working.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this... It's not a force layout, but you should be able to extend it to that pretty easily.

Click on a circle to select it, and then click and drag somewhere else to move them around.

Basically, I'm keeping track of the index of the selected circles in an array, and updating the corresponding data in the `drag` handler.  After the data is updated, I then modify the `cx` and `cy` attributes of the selected circles.

Note: the `drag` handler is attached to a transparent `rect` that covers the entire SVG, and I'm using CSS styles to get the events to cascade to the respective SVG elements correctly with `pointer-events: all;` applied to the `rect`.

```js
 var width = 500,
   height = 500;

 var data = d3.range(10).map(function(d) {
   return {
     x: parseInt(Math.random() * width),
     y: parseInt(Math.random() * height),
     r: parseInt(Math.random() * 10 + 10)
   }
 });

 var selectedNodes = [],
   selectedData = [];

 var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
   .on("drag", dragged)

 var vis = d3.select("#vis").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);

 var dragRect = vis.append("rect")
   .attr("class", "drag")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height)
   .call(drag);

 var nodes = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
   .data(data)
   .enter().append("circle")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("r", function(d) {
     return d.r;
   })
   .attr("cx", function(d) {
     return d.x;
   })
   .attr("cy", function(d) {
     return d.y;
   })
   .on("click", clicked);

 function dragged(d) {
   selectedData.forEach(function(i) {
     data[i].x += d3.event.dx;
     data[i].y += d3.event.dy;
   });

   d3.selectAll("circle.node.selected")
     .attr("cx", function(d) {
       return d.x;
     })
     .attr("cy", function(d) {
       return d.y;
     });
 }

 function clicked(d, i) {
   var j = selectedData.indexOf(i);

   if (j === -1) {
     selectedData.push(i);
     d3.select(this).classed("selected", true);
   } else {
     selectedData.splice(j, 1);
     d3.select(this).classed("selected", false);
   }
 }
```

```css
        rect.drag {
          fill: none;
          pointer-events: all;
        }
        circle.node {
          fill: #000;
        }
        circle.node:hover {
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        circle.node.selected {
          fill: #f00;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="vis"></div>
```