# How to drag an svg group using d3.js drag behavior?

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, d3.js

I am using [D3js drag](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#wiki-on). single element is get dragged perfectly fine. but i want to drag a group of elements.How it can be done. Here is what is on my [Js Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xnjGD/1/):

```
  function onDragDrop(dragHandler, dropHandler) {
        var drag = d3.behavior.drag();

    drag.on("drag", dragHandler)
    .on("dragend", dropHandler);
    return drag;
    }

    var g = d3.select("body").select("svg").append("g")
    .data([{ x: 50, y: 50 }]);

    g.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 40)
    .attr("height", 40)
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("fill","transparent")
    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })
    .call(onDragDrop(dragmove, dropHandler));

    g.append("text")
    .text("Any Text")
    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })
    .call(onDragDrop(dragmove, dropHandler));

    function dropHandler(d) {
       // alert('dropped');
    }

    function dragmove(d) {
        d3.select(this)
      .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)
      .attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y);
    }
```

I want to drag both rect and text simultaneously. Here is what I [tried](http://jsfiddle.net/xnjGD/2/), but no luck. I think am missing something simple.

Comment: You should add your code here, and not just link to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First off, the <g> element doesn't care about `x`and `y` attributes (as in: they're just ignored). You can use `transform="translate(x,y)"` instead.

Second, you will need to check that the element you get in the dragmove handler actually is the <g> element, and not a child element of it. This is because <g> elements have no actual hit area themselves. Their children do though, and the mouse events first go to the children then bubble up to the parent. You can inspect `evt.target` and `evt.currentTarget` to see this in action. `target` is the element that was hit originally, `currentTarget` is the event target that is currently handling the event (e.g the <g> element if the event bubbled up).

Comment: i tried your approach. but elements are blinking on dragging them. have look over here. http://jsfiddle.net/xnjGD/3/

Comment: That's because you're not calling the drag from the <g> element. Here's a simple fixup: http://jsfiddle.net/xnjGD/4/. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078535/stuttering-drag-when-using-d3-behavior-drag-and-transform.

Comment: thanks Erik. you saved me second time.thanks a lot. and here is the final solution of my problem. http://jsfiddle.net/xnjGD/6/

Answer (score 4):

For d3 v4:

```
var drag_this = d3.drag().subject(this)
    .on('start',function (d) {
        if (d.x1){
            d.x1 =  d3.event.x - d.xt;
            d.y1 =  d3.event.y - d.yt;
        }else{
            d.x1 = d3.event.x;
            d.y1 = d3.event.y;
        }
    })
    .on('drag',function(d){
        d3.select(this)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (d3.event.x - d.x1)  + "," + (d3.event.y - d.y1) + ")");

        d.xt = d3.event.x - d.x1;
        d.yt = d3.event.y - d.y1;
    });

my_group.call(drag_this);
```

This assumes that you have data bound to the group.