# d3 drag/ability to redraw line on click, else draw new line

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to merge two stack posts together to get a line drawing tool working, but am having issues. I want to merge this line drawing example here:

[Live drawing of a line in D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273884/live-drawing-of-a-line-in-d3-js)

(there is a jsfiddle in the first response click "live version"). With the properties in of the circle in this post:

[How can I click to add or drag in D3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911514/how-can-i-click-to-add-or-drag-in-d3)

(check the jsfiddle in the first response).

What I want is when you draw a line, it can be dragged upon completion. It can also be redrawn upon completion, say by clicking the line and moving it left/right.

Here is my attempt to merge the two posts: http://jsfiddle.net/da37B/291/

I assume the problem is in the mousedown() function:

```
function mousedown() {
    var m = d3.mouse(this);
    line = vis.append("line")
        .attr("x1", m[0])
        .attr("y1", m[1])
        .attr("x2", m[0])
        .attr("y2", m[1])
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .call(drag)
        .on("click", click);

    vis.on("mousemove", mousemove);
}
```

As you can see, when the line drags upon a click a new line is created, and it also is not able to be redrawn when clicked upon. Also, the drag is only in the orientation of the line.

Comment: Have you tried adding markers to the start and end of each line, and adding the mouse event for redrawing the line specifically to those elements?

Comment: No, I'll try that. When I say redraw I mean the current line can be modified when clicked on.

Comment: Still having trouble with this.