# What's the easiest way to attach a d3 element to the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I looked at some [d3 drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943292/how-to-drag-svg-group-using-d3js-drag-behavior) questions and [examples](http://jsfiddle.net/xnjGD/6/), but I haven't been able to find a way to permanently attach an element to the mouse.

For example, let's say I make some lines in d3:

```
var height  = $(document).height() - 20;
var width   = $(document).width() - 20;
var svgSelection =  
  d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
var lines = 100;

for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++){
    var myLine = svgSelection
        .append("line")
        .attr("x1", Math.random() * width)
        .attr("y1", Math.random() * height) 
        .attr("x2", width/2)
        .attr("y2", height/2)
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke-width", 5)
        .style("visiblity", "visible");
}
```

How would I make it so the `"x1"` and `"y1"` `.attr`s are attached to the mouse location indefinitely? This would mean I could move the `"x2"` and `"y2"` `.attr`s at any time while keeping the other ends of the lines attached to the mouse. Is there an easy way to do this?

(This would just be in any old `<svg>` block, of course.)

Comment: i suspect that you are going to need to change your data and tell d3 that it has been updated, on mousemove events: `$('#canvas').on('mousemove', updateLineData)`

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to attach a mouse handler to your entire SVG and in the handler function get the mouse position and update the coordinates you want. You can see what I'm talking about [here](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347) (click on a node and move the mouse while holding the click).