# d3.js drag group from loaded file

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, drag-and-drop

I am having a problem with dragging a group of elements with d3.js, First I load a external svg file with the following code:

```
    function loadSVG(file) {
        d3.xml(file, "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
            document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement)

            d3.selectAll("g").call(drag).data([{ x: 0, y: 0 }]).enter();

        })
    }
```

As you can see I also set a drag behavior on it with a x and y data which will be used in the `dragMove` function. This so that the drag will be smooth without it jumping around when it starts.

As you can see in the following piece of code I try to access the data (x&y) in the `dragMove` method:

```
    function dragMove(d) {
        d.x += d3.event.dx;
        d.y += d3.event.dy;
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
    }
```

However when I try this code I get the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

My guess is that something went wrong with adding the `x and y data` to the svg group itself. I tried all kind of different way to achieve this but I keep failing. Here is the full script a.t.m.

```
    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on("dragstart", dragStart)
        .on("drag", dragMove)
        .on("dragend", dropHandler);

    //loads a svg file and add it to the body
    function loadSVG(file) {
        d3.xml(file, "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
            document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement)

            d3.selectAll("g").call(drag).data([{ x: 50, y: 50 }]).enter();

        })
    }

    loadSVG("images/layers.svg");

    function dragStart(d) {
    }

    function dragMove(d) {
        d.x += d3.event.dx;
        d.y += d3.event.dy;
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
    }

    function dropHandler(d) {
        // alert('dropped');
    }
```

I got a bit of the info to make this from the following 2 links:
[How to drag an svg group using d3.js drag behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943292/how-to-drag-svg-group-using-d3js-drag-behavior)
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Could it be a problem with the SVG file?

Comment: I hope not, it's a svg file which I am not allowed to change (it is made with a application we have to use, which adds special attributes to it which we have to parse). I will however check it with a clean svg file and see if I get the same error. Thanks for your feedback!