# How do I "register" a dragged group to specific coordinates with d3?

Tags: d3.js, drag

I'm trying to do something that (it seems to me!) should be simple,
but my attempts are getting very convoluted, and I'm looking for d3
guidance.

Suppose I have a dragged group object (consisting of a rectangle and
its text) that has been dropped someplace at the end of a drag.  I want
to "register" this group at specific coordinates.  How do I do that?

I am adding my code to the `dragended()` function associated with
d3.drag's `on("end")` event.

```
function dragended(d) {
    var move = d3.select(this);
    var g = move._groups[0][0];  // same as this!
    var rect = g.children[0]
    rect.x = schedLeft;
    rect.y = schedTop;

    d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
}
```

I bind `d3.select(this)` to the variable `move`, and get an object
like that shown in the attached figure (Chrome developer Local).

[image]

**EDIT**: `move._groups[0][0]` is silly; it's the same as `this`!

Using `this` I can get the group (with child `rect` and
`text` nodes) that I want to move.

`schedLeft` is the x coordinate where I want the group dropped. The `rect` node has `x` and `y` attributes, but my `rect.x = schedLeft`
doesn't change anything (watching in the debugger).

Is that even the right way to have a transition of the entire group
(ie, including the attending `text`) to its new location?

Comment: First: `d3.select(this)._groups[0][0];` is the same of just `this`. Second: what's `schedLef`? What do you want to do here exactly?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, #1 yes, that's true.  #2: `schedLeft` is the x coordinate of the place i want to drop the group.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to hints I found on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15943972/1079688) (from 2013!)  I got it working using this:

```
function dragended(d) {
    // register dragged move into hourSched
    var top = schedTop + (nsched++) * menuWOHgt;
    var transX = newDropX - d.x ;
    var transY = newDropY  - d.y;
    var tstr = `translate( ${transX}, ${transY} )`;
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", tstr)
                    .classed("active", false);
}
```