# D3 zoom pan stutter

Tags: d3.js

I'm experiencing 'stutter' with the D3 drag behavior.

Seems to be a similar problem to ["Stuttering" drag when using d3.behavior.drag() and transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078535/stuttering-drag-when-using-d3-behavior-drag-and-transform)

However the solution does not seem to work for the zoom behavior.

Here is an example of the issue: (try dragging the rectangle)
http://jsfiddle.net/EMNGq/109/

```
blocks = [
  { x: 0, y: 0 }
];

var translate_var = [0,0];

zoom_var = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .on("zoom", function(d) {
    d.x = d3.event.x;
    d.y = d3.event.y;
    draw();
  });

svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", 600)
  .attr("height", 600);

function draw() {
  g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(blocks);

  gEnter = g.enter().append("g")
    .call(zoom_var);

  g.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+translate_var[0]+","+translate_var[1]+")"; });

  gEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("width", 100);
}

draw()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You zoom in or drag the element, but then translate the same element. Because the translation is relative, it results in this *stuttering*.

As stated in the [documentation for Zoom Behavior](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior):

> This behavior automatically creates event listeners to handle zooming and panning gestures on a **container element**. Both mouse and touch events are supported.

Contrast it to the [documentation for Drag Behavior](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior):

> This behavior automatically creates event listeners to handle drag gestures on an **element**. Both mouse events and touch events are supported.

Your solution is inverse to the similar question. Call your zoom function on the container.

```
svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", 600)
  .attr("height", 600)
  .call(zoom_var);
```

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mhoa20o5/).

You might also be interested in the actual zoom. To do that simply add the `scale` to your `transform` rule. Here's the [demo with zoom enabled](http://jsfiddle.net/e13bp2b1/).

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on why it behaves differently to pan? Is the pan behavior not relative? Many thanks!